# Sharing a file system, or how to horizontally scale access to files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, linux-networking

My API mostly serves up stuff from the database, but a big part of the product is generating images by combining SVG files with large pattern fills (~50MB tiff files).

The API can scale horizontally, but each instance would need access to the file system somehow. Is there a solid way to share/mount the file system between multiple API nodes, or do I need to make a separate file service that provides them over HTTP or something?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend you look at an NFS solution. It does exactly what you're saying you need done.